# How to use interfaces that expect `const char*` if I'm working with `std::byte`s

Tags: c++, c++17

With C++17 `std::byte` was added. However, all these legacy interfaces expect `const char*` for an array of bytes (for example, libpng does). If I'm representing bytes in my code as a container of `std::byte` objects (for example, `std::vector<std::byte>`), how do I make use of these interfaces?

Comment: If the interfaces you want to use are based on `char`, why would you use `std::byte`?

Comment: @NeilButterworth I thought explicitness was one of the reasons `std::byte` came to existence? I.e., saying "this thing here is a *byte*, not a *character*."

Comment: But in your case your interfaces seem to be  expecting characters, not bytes. If you think writing code that will require reinterpret_casts all over the place is a good idea, then I have to disagree, no matter how "explicit" it might be.

Comment: No; the interfaces expect bytes, but given that they're legacy interfaces, they have no better way to express this than `char`. Do you seriously think that libpng functions expect the *characters* of an image rather than the *bytes* of an image? Also, I see nothing wrong with having a nice interface and (correct and well-defined) `reinterpret_cast`s in your implementation. I'd probably have a function called `as_characters` or sth do the `reinterpret_cast`ing anyways, rather than spamming the ugly `reinterpret_cast` as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a contiguous buffer of `std::byte`s, a reinterpretation of a `std::byte*` to a `char*` is legal by design and doesn't violate the strict aliasing rule:

([wording from the most recent revision of the `std::byte` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0298r3.pdf))

> Lvalues and rvalues [basic.lval]
>
> 8. If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>
>    - [...]
>    - (8.8) a `char`, `unsigned char`, or `std::byte` type.

(note: the "or `std::byte`" is added by the proposal)

So you can use `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(pointer_to_std_byte_buffer)` or `static_cast<const char*>(static_cast<const void*>(pointer_to_std_byte_buffer))` or `(const char*)pointer_to_std_byte_buffer`, depending on what your style guide says.

Comment: No style guide should ever suggest the double-cast.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using std::byte you'll have to cast when passing to something that expects the elements to be char:

```
(char const *)&myVec[0]
```

Comment: Note that this is only valid if the vector's size is non-zero.

Comment: Using C casts should be discouraged in modern C++ code. Use `reinterpret_cast` instead.

Comment: Is this solution portable?